# Find all entries where nullable DateTime contains keyword

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have a model with a nullable DateTime. I'm trying to use an `IQueryable` object and find all entries where the DateTime matches to a string, if set:

```
query.Where(s => s.MyDate.HasValue && s.MyDate.Value.ToString("{ 0:dd.MM.yyyy}").Contains(keyword));
```

However this doesn't work as an exception is thrown: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

As I've done some research, the problem seems to be that my where condition can't be translated to SQL.

How can I solve this problem?

Example data shown to the user:

- `10.03.2017`
- `01.08.2017`

Possible search terms:

- 08
- 08.07.
- 08.07.2017
- 8.07.2017
- ...

Comment: Do it in .NET, or write the SQL yourself, Linq to entities really cannot handle this oddity so you need to do it yourself in either world.

Comment: I would recommend you don't do this at all. What happens if you search for `08/07/2017` for example? How about if you're American (i.e. `mm/dd`) versus elsewhere (i.e. `dd/mm`)?

Comment: Well, I don't care at all. I just want the user to be able to search for a date (or a part of a date) in a format he knows.

Comment: `ToString` method should placed outside the query - only constant values or aggregate functions allowed inside LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: I have a complex query inside my method with a lot of conditions inside my `Where`. My method creates the `IQueryable` only and returns it to the caller. The caller calls `ToList()`. That would mean that 90% of the where conditions could be processed inside my query, but 10% of it (all where ToString comes in place) would have to be proceeded outside. From an architectural point of view that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself about not caring. As long as you have a DateTime.ToString() call in this code with a format string, you have to pay attention to whether it is dd/mm or mm/dd.

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't concerned about date formats (assuming the user knows what they are querying) just use the SQL Server default conversion:

```
query.Where(s => s.MyDate.HasValue && s.MyDate.Value.ToString().Contains(keyword));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using the Entity Framework: Lets assume s is type DemoClass:

```
public partial class DemoClass 
{
  public Nullable<DateTime> MyDate;
  ...
}
```

would be the DemoClass.cs for your Entity. Just have an additional partial class in an extra file (this is the best way otherwise EF could override your edits if you're using the designer e.g.):

DemoClass_Additional.cs

```
public partial class DemoClass 
{
  [NotMapped]
  public string MyDateString {
    get
    { 
      if(this.MyDate.HasValue)
      {
        return this.MyDate.Value.ToString("{ 0:dd.MM.yyyy}");
      }
      else
      {
        return "";
      }
    }
}
```

[NotMapped] will exclude the property from the database mapping and finally your query would be

```
 query.Where(s => s.MyDate.HasValue && s.MyDateString.Contains(keyword));
```